# Forcing figure with 4 subfigures to span over twocolumns

Tags: floats, subfloats

I tried:

```
\begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/a}
                \caption{a}
                \label{fig:a}
        \end{subfigure}%

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/b}
                \caption{b}
                \label{fig:b}
        \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/c}
                \caption{c}
                \label{fig:c}
        \end{subfigure}
         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/d}
                \caption{d}
                \label{fig:d}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Pictures of ABCD}\label{fig:ABCD}
\end{figure*}
```

but the figures appeared on one column vertically!
How can I force these 4 figures to span horizontally on both columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blank lines inbetween the subfigure environments causes a line-break inside the figure environment, hence removing those blank lines where you want to remain in the same line in the produced document gives you the desired result:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/a}
            \caption{a}
            \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/b}
            \caption{b}
            \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/c}
            \caption{c}
            \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/d}
            \caption{d}
            \label{fig:d}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures of ABCD}\label{fig:ABCD}
\end{figure*}
```

**Addendum**:

You might as well "comment the blank lines out"--so to say--if you want to preserve readability of the source:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/a}
            \caption{a}
            \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    % this comment avoids break-line...
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/b}
            \caption{b}
            \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/c}
            \caption{c}
            \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}
    % ... this comment too
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/d}
            \caption{d}
            \label{fig:d}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures of ABCD}\label{fig:ABCD}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Probably only one row is wanted, judging from `0.25\textwidth`; but it would be better to have `0.24`, in order to avoid overfull.

Comment: If the figures were to be in one row, I'd agree that the width should rather be `0.24\textwidth`. But the question was how to span 4 figures over 2 columns, indeed.